# How to change the atributte of an object in ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am starting to study angular and came across the following situation:

```
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <h3>What is the disease?</h3>
    <div class="container" >
        <div class='col-2' *ngFor="let disease of diseases;let i= index"> 
              <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"  [(ngModel)]="paciente.disease" name="inlinecheckbox{{i}}" id="inlinecheckbox{{i}}" >
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlinecheckbox{{i}}">{{disease}}</label>
                </div>
        </div>
       <p *ngIf="pacient.disease==true && disease=='fever'">
          <input type="radio" name="high">High Fever
          <input type="radio" name="Average">Average Fever
          <input type="radio" name="low">Low Fever
       </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Basically I'm trying to `checkbox` for each disease and each time I click I change the value in the corresponding attribute in patient and open another dialog tree.

This is the the control of the class:

```
patient:Patient; 
diseases=["fever","faintness","tiredness"];
```

and that's the model:

```
export class Patient{
  fever:boolean
  faintness:boolean
  tiredness:boolean
}
```

As I am doing now, each time I click on an option all are marked. How to solve and is it possible to solve in the way I'm following?

Comment: what is inside `paciente` variable

Comment: you have nothing called disease in `patient`

Comment: Sorry,pacient is the untranslated word to the patient. I 
adjusted now

Comment: check the other comment `patient.disease` is undefined

Comment: Yes,that's the problem. i'm trying to use ngfor to change the attribute to go through each disease

Comment: try patient `[(ngModel)]="patient[disease]"`

Comment: did it worked ?

Comment: apparently yes, has stopped selecting all checkboxes. But a 'p' tag no longer appears when I click

Comment: have you changed both `patient.disease` to `patient[disease]'?

Comment: No! It worked! 
I changed the .disease for [disease] and it worked! thank you very much!

Comment: I will make a post to answer please mark as answered thank you in advance

Comment: I thank you, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <h3>What is the disease?</h3>
    <div class="container" >
        <div class='col-2' *ngFor="let disease of diseases;let i= index"> 
              <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"  [(ngModel)]="patient[disease]" name="inlinecheckbox{{i}}" id="inlinecheckbox{{i}}" >
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlinecheckbox{{i}}">{{disease}}</label>
                </div>
        </div>
       <p *ngIf="patient[disease]==true && disease=='fever'">
          <input type="radio" name="high">High Fever
          <input type="radio" name="Average">Average Fever
          <input type="radio" name="low">Low Fever
       </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

there is no such thing as a `disease`attribute inside your class instead you probably want to do `patient[disease]`

for example if `disease` of `diseases` equals `'fever'` then your call to the boolean variable would be `patient['fever']` which is the same as `patient[disease]` and which is the same as `patient.fever`